# Mifare Plus X vulnerabilities

Tags: nfc, mifare

I have just purchased a Mifare Plus X (MF1PLUSx0) for a security project. I know that there are exploits against Mifare Classic cards (using tools such as Mfoc and Mfcuk), but are there similar exploits to crack the Mifare Plus X card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mifare Plus product line was specifically designed as a solution to the well known Mifare Classic vulnerabilities. As far as I know there are currently no published exploits against this new generation of cards.